# Skip installation of Command Line Tools when installing Homebrew on macos

Tags: macos, homebrew, xcode-command-line-tools

I am installing homebrew on macOS High Sierra 10.13. I have already installed the Command Line Tools for Xcode which is a requirement for homebrew. When installation of homebrew starts I am forced to install command line tools (or abort). When I do this the installation process hangs. I don't understand why this hangs but more importantly I don't understand why it is trying to install CLT when I can show that they are already available on my machine.

Comment: do you have the latest version of Xcode?  CLT updated with the latest version of XCode.

Comment: I installed CLT earlier this week and I just did a check for available software updates and Xcode is not there so I imagine that's not the problem.

Comment: i have Xcode version 9.4.1

Comment: Please don’t add the [brew] tag; it has nothing to do with [homebrew].

Comment: facing this problem with Xcode 11.2, though I have Xcode11.2 installed brew installation shows "Installing Command Line Tools for Xcode-11.0"

Answer (score 9):

1. Right click the link below and save it as `homebrew-install.sh`
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh
2. Open `homebrew-install.sh` with a text editor and change the definition of the method `should_install_command_line_tools` to `return 1`
3. Make `homebrew-install.sh` executable (by running `chmod u+x homebrew-install.sh`) and then run `./homebrew-install.sh`

Comment: There is no method to return. Check your link

Comment: @E.Praneeth, thanks. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the xcode command line tools can be installed.

My environment is mac os.

In the terminal please enter

```
xcode-select --install
```

And it takes a little time to install

Check out macOS requirements in this article [https://docs.brew.sh/Installation]

good luck.